# Using maxval or minval functions

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Problems using minval and maxval functions with allocatable vectors.

The example is only to show the error message.
The component H on Refl_Type will have as minimum a dimension 3 (for h, k and l indices).

Any easy workaround?

Program Check
      implicit none

```
  !> Type definitions
  Type :: Refl_Type
     integer,dimension(:), allocatable :: H            ! H
     integer                           :: Mult  =0     ! Mutiplicity
  End Type Refl_Type

  Type, extends(Refl_Type) :: SRefl_Type
     real :: Fo    =0.0  ! Observed Structure Factor
     real :: Fc    =0.0  ! Calculated Structure Factor
  End Type SRefl_Type

  Type :: RefList_Type
     integer                                     :: Nref
     class(refl_Type), dimension(:), allocatable :: Reflections
  end Type RefList_Type

  Type(RefList_Type) :: List

  Contains

  Subroutine Sub(List)
     !---- Argument ----!
     type (RefList_Type), intent(in out) :: List

     !---- Local Variables ----!
     integer            :: n
     integer            :: hmax,kmax,lmax
     integer            :: hmin,kmin,lmin

     n=List%Nref

     hmax=maxval(list%reflections(1:n)%h(1))
     kmax=maxval(list%reflections(1:n)%h(2))
     lmax=maxval(list%reflections(1:n)%h(3))


   End Subroutine Sub

End Program Check
```

I have the next error compilation
...

```
 hmax=maxval(list%reflections(1:n)%h(1))
                  1

Error: Component to the right of a part reference with nonzero rank must not have the ALLOCATABLE attribute at (1)
```

Comment: manipulating array slices is ony authorized when the stride in each direction is constant. This is not the case here : the distance in memory of two consécutives terms in your "vector" (list%reflections(1:n)%h(1) for instance) is not constant.

Comment: if H was just declared dimension(3) (without allocatable), then your programming would be OK

Comment: I guess we can try hmax = maxval( [( list%reflections( i )%h(1), i=1,n )] )

Comment: Uhmmm! This a bit tricky. Intel compiler do it without problems. For me, the easier form is do a local copy (using allocate variable) to keep all indices.